# Bandwidth of a signal

Tags: bandwidth

Given a complex,with fmin<0(say -10) and fmax>0(say 30) what is the bandwidth of this signal.Is it form fmin to fmax ,or 0 to fmax?
Thank you!

Comment: A good answer to this question by is here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/53909/passband-vs-baseband-bandwidth

Comment: Sooo fmax-fmin?

Comment: Matt's answer at that link @Engineer gave you is consistent with fmax-fmin, and I would agree with that. You could also be clearer by saying it is the two-sided bandwidth.